# C# create resources programmatically

Tags: c#, resources, memory-mapped-files

I've been researching for a method to add a resource programmatically.

Basically I'm reading some values from a memory mapped file. I want to be able to create a resource string to store the values read.

For example:

```
MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("test");

using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
{
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
    accessor.ReadArray<byte>(0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    String S = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
}
```

I want to be able to put that string into a resource file

Comment: People can be free to correct me on this, but I was under the impression that resources were compiled into the executable so adding new ones after compilation wouldn't be so straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i wanted exactly is to store data somewhere instead of file or a Database , because it was only an `ID` so i solved it by storing it on a `Registrey Key`
on the `current user` so it won't need any admin privilieges .